# Angular 2 Dynamic Tabs

Tags: angular, tabs

**index.html**

```
<project></project>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, NgModule, HostListener, Inject, Pipe, PipeTransform, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Tabs} from './project/tabs';
import {Tab} from './project/tab';
import {FilterPipe} from './_directives/filter.pipe';
import {ProjectService} from './_services/project.service';

declare var Swiper: Object;

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: 'project/project.component.html'
})

export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
   images: string[];
   index: Int8Array;
   config: Object = {
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      centeredSlides: true,
      spaceBetween: 200,
      effect: 'coverflow',
      speed: 1000,
      pagination: '.header-swiper-front .swiper-pagination',
      paginationClickable: true,
      nextButton: '.header-swiper-front .swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.header-swiper-front .swiper-button-prev',
      coverflow: {
      slideShadows: true
    },
    roundLengths: true,
    activeIndex: 1
};


   constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {
      this.loadAllImage();
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   private loadAllImage() {
       this.projectService.getAll().subscribe(image => {this.images = image})
   }

}
```

**project.component.html**

```
<tabs (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
<tab tabTitle="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</tab>  // <-- working
<tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 3'">Tab 3 Content</tab>  //  <-- working

    <tab *ngFor="let image of images | keys; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i" tabTitle="{{image.key}}">  //<-- not working
        <div *ngFor="let projectData of image.value" >{{ projectData.name }}</div>
    </tab>  
</tabs>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
import {Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Tab} from './tab';

@Component({
selector: 'tabs',
template: `
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{tab.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ng-content></ng-content>
`
})
export class Tabs implements AfterContentInit{
@ContentChildren(Tab) tabs: QueryList<Tab>;
// contentChildren are set
ngAfterContentInit() {
    // get all active tabs
    let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.active);

    // if there is no active tab set, activate the first
    if (activeTabs.length === 0) {
        this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
    }
}
selectTab(tab: Tab) {
    // deactivate all tabs
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    console.log(this.tabs)
    // activate the tab the user has clicked on.
    tab.active = true;
}
}
```

**tab.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'tab',
styles: [`
.pane{
  padding: 1em;
}
`],
template: `
<div [hidden]="!active" class="pane">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
`
})
export class Tab {
  @Input('tabTitle') title: string;
  @Input() active = false;
}
```

**Project.service.tc**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class ProjectService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getAll() { 
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/AngularTest/api/user.php')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

**Response of Backend URL:**

```
{
"Android": [
    {
        "name": "Go to Market tomorrow",
        "imagePath": "01-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "Android"
    },
    {
        "name": "Email to manager",
        "imagePath": "02-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "Android"
    },
    {
        "name": "Go For Running",
        "imagePath": "04-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "Android"
    },
    {
        "name": "Go to Movie",
        "imagePath": "05-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "Android"
    },
    {
        "name": "Go to Home",
        "imagePath": "06-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "Android"
    },
    {
        "name": "Schneider Electric",
        "imagePath": "test.jpg",
        "description": "Explore and put Schneider Electric and Square D products and solutions at your fingertips! This app offers interactive 3D product demonstrations of features, benefits and product overviews. Many offer removable modules to see inside and all can be viewed in 360 degree rotation.",
        "TechnologyName": "Android"
    }
],
"IOS": [
    {
        "name": "Push code to GitHub",
        "imagePath": "03-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "IOS"
    }
],
"UNITY": [
    {
        "name": "Go to office",
        "imagePath": "07-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "UNITY"
    },
    {
        "name": "Push code to finish",
        "imagePath": "08-screenshot.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "TechnologyName": "UNITY"
    }
]
}
```

When I console.log() in a **tabs.ts** Display _result 2 Array but when I Expand then it shown 5 Array Elelment, so when page is load at that time load only 2 array element which I declare in html page as static and other one are dynamic so this dynamic element not working.

[image]

Please Guide me What I need to change ?

Comment: QueryList don't seams to be a object that NgFor can handle. Try to put the tabs variable as a standard array object.

Comment: also try to change tabTitle="{{image.key}}" to [tabTitle]="image.key"

Comment: How can I put tabs Variable as Standard Array object ? @1st4ck

Comment: When Page is loading at that time only gives _result as 2 array after click on any tab then its return 5 array. what I miss this. I added comment in project.component.html.